# AttributeError: module 'tabula' has no attribute 'read_pdf'

Tags: java, python-3.x, tabula-py

I've tried to get tabula-py to work, and followed different advised still it doesn't acknowledge that read_pdf exist, i.e i got the error message "AttributeError: module 'tabula' has no attribute 'read_pdf'"

here is the code snippet:

```py
import tabula

tab = tabula.read_pdf(path)
```

I have java installed:

java version "1.8.0_381"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_381-b09)

I'm running on a mac os.

I tried to run `pip install tabula`, but as that was wrong apparently I ran `pip uninstall tabula` and then `pip install tabula-py`.

I installed java using `brew install java`

Comment: why dont you use python `help` or `dis` to see what your tabula-py module DOES have?  also what does java have to do with this?

Comment: A better way to ask the question would that: how to use tabula to read a PDF in Python into a variable. You should first read the relevant tabula documentation: https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ . Java is a different programming language and environment, please do not mix it with the original problem, they are unrelated.

Comment: When I installed tabula, it explicitly said it was dependent on Java.